# Monitoring the limit values​of the limit_req_zone directive

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting, ngx-http-limit-req-module

For example I have some configuration with limit_req and burst values

```
http {
server {
    ...
    location /some-location/ {
        limit_req zone=one burst=100;
    }
    location /some-other-location/ {
        limit_req zone=two burst=200;
    }
    ....
```

Is there any way to monitor or be notified in case when "burst" values by location is close to limits
For example 75% of "burst" quota is reached.
I mean when awaitng requests count for /some-location/ location is equal 75 and for /some-other-location/ is 150